# Need a PHP script to return an exact match of a python script

Tags: php, python, md5

Please I need help getting the exact md5 value of this python script in PHP

### The Python script

```
def md5code(params):
    params = {'identifier': ' ', 'amount': '0.0', 'code': 'UNIA'}
    req = dict([[key, params.get(key, '')] for key in ['code', 'identifier', 'amount']]) 
    secret = '2fd0bba6b1774ed391c1ff8467f52a5d'
    text = ":".join([req[x] for x in ['code', 'identifier', 'amount']] + secret)
    return md5(text).hexdigest().upper()
```

The return value is: 5D316CD2311678A1B12F6152988F3097

### The PHP script

```
$secret = '2fd0bba6b1774ed391c1ff8467f52a5d';
$code = 'UNIA';
$valid_institution = array('amount' => '0.0', 'code' => $code, 'identifier' => ' ');
foreach($valid_institution as $k => $v) {
    $text = implode(":", $v[$k] + $secret);
}
print strtoupper(hash("md5", $text));
```

The return value is: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E

I'm expecting the PHP script to return an exact md5 value, but it is not.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @stereofrog Yes! No difference in output.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a function? Have you tried to actually take care of the order of the parameters you make use of? Have you actually validated if python md5().hexdigest() matches php's hash() function? Have you .... ? .... ??????? - The code obviously has tons of issues and it looks like that the one who wrote it actually did not care much about coding. Your question sounds a bit that you want to get the job done by others.

Comment: Not valid Python code to begin with because of `[ ... ] + secret`

Comment: @hakre It's an inherited project and I have to extend what exists instead of changing it. I don't think there's anything wrong with that. So marking it as not useful is vague and rude. You don't know why it is needed. So why pass a biase and needless conclusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, seems you're using foreach in a wrong way. Try this:

```
$secret = '2fd0bba6b1774ed391c1ff8467f52a5d';
$code = 'UNIA';
$valid_institution = array('amount' => '0.0', 'code' => $code, 'identifier' => ' ');
$text = 
    $valid_institution['code'] . ":" . 
    $valid_institution['identifier'] . ":" . 
    $valid_institution['amount'] . ":" . 
    $secret;

print strtoupper(hash("md5", $text));
```

Comment: Without changing the Python code, this gave the exact Python md5 result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Valid Python code could look like this:

```
from hashlib import md5
params = {'identifier': ' ', 'amount': '0.0', 'code': 'UNIA'}
req = dict([[key, params.get(key, '')] for key in ['code', 'identifier', 'amount']]) 
secret = '2fd0bba6b1774ed391c1ff8467f52a5d'
text = ":".join(req[x] for x in ['code', 'identifier', 'amount']) + secret
print md5(text).hexdigest().upper()
```

and this is the equivalent PHP

```
<?php
$secret = '2fd0bba6b1774ed391c1ff8467f52a5d';
$code = 'UNIA';
$valid_institution = array(
    'code' => $code, 
    'identifier' => ' ',
    'amount' => '0.0');

$text = implode(':', $valid_institution) . $secret;
print strtoupper(hash("md5", $text)); 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Different PHP md5 result but gave a match in equality comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
$secret = '2fd0bba6b1774ed391c1ff8467f52a5d';
$code = 'UNIA';
$valid_institution = array('amount' => '0.0', 'code' => $code, 'identifier' => ' ');
$text = implode(":", $valid_institution). $secret;
print strtoupper(hash("md5", $text));
```